# I need to compare hive table schema with a data frame which contains schema of a csv file

Tags: scala, csv, hadoop, apache-spark, dataframe

here I am trying to validate structure of hive table and CSV file which is stored in s3.

This is schema of CSV file in dataframe.

```
+----+----------------+----+---+-----------+-----------+
|S_No|        Variable|Type|Len|     Format|   Informat|
+----+----------------+----+---+-----------+-----------+
|   1|        DATETIME| Num|  8|DATETIME20.|DATETIME20.|
|   2|   LOAD_DATETIME| Num|  8|DATETIME20.|DATETIME20.|
|   3|     SOURCE_BANK|Char| 1 |       null|       null|
|   4|        EMP_NAME|Char| 50|       null|       null|
|   5|HEADER_ROW_COUNT| Num|  8|       null|       null|
|   6|      EMP _HOURS| Num|  8|       15.2|       15.1|
+----+----------------+----+---+-----------+-----------+
```

I need to compare it with O/p of

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveContext
val targetTableName = "TableA"
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
val sqlContext = new org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext(sc)
val targetRawData = hc.sql("Select datetime,load_datetime,trim(source_bank) as source_bank,trim(emp_name) as emp_name,header_row_count, emp_hours from " + targetTableName)

val schema= targetRawData.schema
```

which is :schema: `org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType = StructType(StructField(datetime,TimestampType,true), StructField(load_datetime,TimestampType,true), StructField(source_bank,StringType,true), StructField(emp_name,StringType,true), StructField(header_row_count,IntegerType,true), StructField(emp_hours,DoubleType,true))`

Comment: Compare how? What's the expected output?

Comment: I want to check whether the schema of hive table is exactly same as of csv file.  If its same we need to get output in different hive table as any non zero value

Comment: And have you tried using `==` on the schemas?

Comment: You don't have to use Scala... You literally put two schemas on both sides of an `==` to compare them

Comment: I advanced a bit, Now I have two dataframes and need to compare these two:scala> df2.show
+----------------+-------------+
|        Variable|         type|
+----------------+-------------+  and other one as mentioned above can you please tell m
|        datetime|TimestampType|
|   load_datetime|TimestampType|
|     source_bank|   StringType|
|        emp_name|   StringType|
|header_row_count|  IntegerType|
|       emp_hours|   DoubleType|
+----------------+-------------+

Comment: Again ... `df.schema == df2.schema`... Did you try it?

Answer (score 1):

you can use MegaSparDiff an open source too that compares multiple types of datasources including S3, HIVE, CSV, JDBC etc.

https://github.com/FINRAOS/MegaSparkDiff

the below pair will return inLeftButNotInRight and inRightButNotInLeft as DataFrames.

Your success condition is if both DataFrames have zero records, this means the data is identical. 
Now you might wanna consider not loading all the data since you are interested in comparing the schema only.

```
 SparkFactory.initializeSparkContext();

    AppleTable leftAppleTable = SparkFactory.parallelizeTextSource("S3://file1","table1");

    AppleTable rightAppleTable = SparkFactory.parallelizeHiveSource("select * from hivetable","hivetable");

    Pair<Dataset<Row>, Dataset<Row>> resultPair = SparkCompare.compareAppleTables(leftAppleTable, rightAppleTable);

    if (resultPair.getLeft().count() != 0 && resultPair.getRight().count() != 0)
    {
        //success condition
    }

    SparkFactory.stopSparkContext();
```

Answer (score 1):

```
  Naveen
    you can follow the below steps:

    define a class:


    import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
    import org.apache.spark.sql.SQLImplicits
    import org.apache.spark.sql._

    class columnMatch(spark:SparkSession,inputdf: DataFrame, requiredColNames: Array[String]) {

    val missingColumns = requiredColNames.diff(inputdf.columns)

    def missingColumnsMessage(): String = {
        val missingColNames = missingColumns.mkString(", ")
        val allColNames = inputdf.columns.mkString(", ")


        s"The [${missingColNames}] columns are not included in the DataFrame with the following columns [${allColNames}]"

    def validatePresenceOfColumns(): String = {
        if (missingColumns.nonEmpty) {

          missingColumnsMessage()
        }
          else{
            s"No Mismatch in the column Name Found"
          }


      }
      }
```